# How to use specific color from an image texture as factor/mask in cycles mix node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to use all red pixels of my image texture as mask . I know how to do this in compositor but I dont know how to do this in shader editor.
I saw someone doing it on twitter but I cant find that tweet now. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add node>Converter>Separate RGB.